# Using an insert statement in stored procedure to copy some info from one table and insert new info from VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I an creating a stored procedure that will copy some of the columns from table 1 and insert their values into a new entry on table 2. At the same time, 4 columns on the new entry on table 2 need to be updated with the date, user name, and two variables from a button on a VBA userform.

I know how to do these things individually, but I'm unsure how to get them to work together. I could make two statements but I need them both to go to the same entry on table 2, not two separate entries.

Here are the two statements I would like to combine into one stored procedure to create one new entry from a VBA button click.

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [PIA].[dbo].[AttendanceHistory] ON 
INSERT INTO [PIA].[dbo].[AttendanceHistory] (FirstName, LastName, AgentName, Location,
              EmployeeGroup, ContractAgency, Manager, Supervisor, Team, Title, Position, 
              Staffcimid, FTPT, Bilingual, Five9Email, Email, Weekdayschedule, 
              Weekendschedule, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, Exception, Exceptionreason)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, AgentName, Location, EmployeeGroup, ContractAgency, Manager, 
       Supervisor,Team, Title, Position, Staffcimid, FTPT, Bilingual, Five9Email, Email, 
       Weekdayschedule, Weekendschedule
FROM dbo.Attendance WHERE dbo.Attendance.Agentname = @Agent

Set [CreatedDate] = GETDATE and 
    [CreatedBy] = @userid and 
    [Exception] = @except and 
    [ExceptionReason] = @Exceptreason
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps :)

```
INSERT INTO [PIA].[dbo].[AttendanceHistory] (FirstName,LastName,AgentName,Location,EmployeeGroup,ContractAgency,Manager,Supervisor,Team,Title,Position,Staffcimid,FTPT,Bilingual,Five9Email,Email,Weekdayschedule,Weekendschedule,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,Exception,Exceptionreason)
SELECT FirstName,LastName,AgentName,Location,EmployeeGroup,ContractAgency,Manager,Supervisor,Team,Title,Position,Staffcimid,FTPT,Bilingual,Five9Email,Email,Weekdayschedule,Weekendschedule, GETDATE() , @userid, @except, @Exceptreason
FROM dbo.Attendance WHERE dbo.Attendance.Agentname = @Agent
```

Comment: Please explain for posterity what your answer adjusted. Just reading code is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is passing the variables in the select clause as following:

```
INSERT INTO [PIA].[dbo].[AttendanceHistory] (FirstName, LastName, AgentName, Location,
              EmployeeGroup, ContractAgency, Manager, Supervisor, Team, Title, Position, 
              Staffcimid, FTPT, Bilingual, Five9Email, Email, Weekdayschedule, 
              Weekendschedule, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, Exception, Exceptionreason)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, AgentName, Location, EmployeeGroup, ContractAgency, Manager, 
       Supervisor,Team, Title, Position, Staffcimid, FTPT, Bilingual, Five9Email, Email, 
       Weekdayschedule, Weekendschedule, GETDATE() , @userid, @except, @Exceptreason
FROM dbo.Attendance WHERE dbo.Attendance.Agentname = @Agent
```

`GETDATE() , @userid, @except, @Exceptreason` are added along with column list of table `Attendence` thus resulting as constant fields.